# How to keep adding conditions to an existing Firestore query?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, filter

Without any filters applied, I am querying my Firestore database like this:

```
var query:Query = db.collection("myFirestoreData")

queryData()
```

My app also has 4 buttons for filtering.
[image]

For example, if "Cheap" is tapped, this is how I'm filtering for the data where `isCheap = true`:

```
if cheapOnly == true {
             query = query
                .whereField("isCheap", isEqualTo: true)
        }
```

If someone *also* taps "Easy", how can I have *both* filters applied (i.e., filter for data where both `isCheap = true` and `isEasy = true`? I thought I could just add another `whereField` condition to the `query` reference like this:

```
if cheapOnly == true {
             query = query
                .whereField("isCheap", isEqualTo: true)
        }
if easyOnly == true {
             query = query
                .whereField("isEasy", isEqualTo: true)
        }
```

All of the above code runs when both buttons are tapped, but I continue to just get one or the other filtering. How can I:

1. Apply querying conditions on top of one another (i.e., filter by *both* Easy and Cheap)?, and
2. Have it not matter which order the filters were tapped in (i.e., same result whether Easy or Cheap was tapped first/second)?

Any support/guidance is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Added the full code of my data model below to see if someone can spot something incorrect there.

```
class MealPlanModel {
    
    var delegate:MealPlanProtocol?
    var listener:ListenerRegistration?
    var mealPlan = [MealPlan]()
    
    func getMealPlans(starred starredOnly:Bool = false, textToQuery searchText:String = "", easyFiltered easyOnly:Bool = false,  cheapFiltered cheapOnly:Bool = false, highProteinFiltered highProteinOnly:Bool = false, vegetarianFiltered vegetarianOnly:Bool = false) {

        // Detach any listener
        listener?.remove()
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        var query:Query = db.collection("mealPlans")
        
        if cheapOnly == true {
             query = query
                .whereField("isCheap", isEqualTo: true)
        }
        
        if easyOnly == true {
             query = query
                .whereField("isEasy", isEqualTo: true)
        }

        func queryData() {
            
            self.listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
                
                // Check for errors
                if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                    
                    var mealPlans = [MealPlan]()
                    
                    // Parse documents into mealPlans
                    for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                        
                        let m = MealPlan(
                            docID: doc["docID"] as? String,
                            title: doc["title"] as? String)
                        
                        mealPlans.append(m)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.delegate?.mealPlansRetrieved(mealPlans: mealPlans)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        
        queryData()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you shared in your question looks fine at first glance. It might be easier to help if you can show a single snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen! I added the rest of the code in my data model. Do you spot anything incorrect in there? I'm wondering if I'm perhaps calling `queryData()` in the wrong places and so the query is resetting between my `if` statements.

Comment: Can you print `running query data with isEasy and isCheap` inside of `queryData` function? So we know the function is running and values of both isEasy and isCheap is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
if easyOnly == true || cheapOnly == true || highProteinOnly == true || vegetarianOnly == true {
            
            // Reset the query
            db.collection("mealPlans").document().getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                
                self.query = db.collection("mealPlans")
                
                // Refine the query based on the button taps
                if easyOnly == true {
                    self.query = self.query
                    .whereField("isEasy", isEqualTo: true)
                }
                
                if cheapOnly == true {
                    self.query = self.query
                    .whereField("isCheap", isEqualTo: true)
                }
                
                if highProteinOnly == true {
                    self.query = self.query
                    .whereField("isHighProtein", isEqualTo: true)
                }
                
                if vegetarianOnly == true {
                    self.query = self.query
                    .whereField("isVegetarian", isEqualTo: true)
                }

                queryData()
             }
        } else {
            db.collection("mealPlans").document().getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                
                self.query = db.collection("mealPlans")
             
                queryData()
             }
        }
```

`self.query = db.collection("mealPlans")` helped reset the query when multiple buttons were pressed.

`queryData()` was implemented at the end of each query to submit the query after all `.whereField` parameters were set.

Answer (score 0):

So, by my understanding you want to allow multiple true conditions, only if selected? I did something very similar, funnily enough, a food app like yours. It's simply about "manipulating" the reference to your database like so:

```
var ref = db.collection("myFirestoreData")
    if cheapOnly {
       ref = ref.whereField("isCheap", isEqualTo: true)
            }
    if easyOnly {
        ref = ref.whereField("isEasy", isEqualTo: true)
       }

  ref.limit(to: 20).getDocuments {
        //Get your documents
    }
```

This is on the presumption that you are passing the values of your options i.e. cheap, easy etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the example! It seems to me that mine follows a similar structure as yours. I posted the rest of the relevant code in my data model. Do you think there's something incorrect in there? Is it possible that I'm calling `queryData()` in the wrong place?

Comment: @amirbt17 Why are you using a listener? A listener should really only be used for updates from Firebase, it can get quite costly when using a listener. You simply want to grab your reference, query how you see fit and use `.getDocuments`. In your `getDocuments` closure you transform the data etc.